# Excel: Date format is throwing up random numbers when using a function

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am using a `INDEX, MATCH` function in sheet `Car Search` to pull data from sheet `Raw Data`. One of the cells is **Date Purchased**, this will show the date in format *dd/mm/yyyy* (UK Format).

The problem is, when I enter a date in this format, it doesn't correctly pull over to the `Car Search` sheet. Instead, it shows up 42350 when I entered 12/12/2015 in the `Raw Data` sheet.
Both cells have been formatted to Date, but it is still showing up as 42350 and not 12/12/2015.

Is it because the function is preventing it from showing date format?
Anybody know why Excel does this? I have tried on a new sheet, but same result.

[image: Car Search Sheet]
[image: Raw Data Sheet]

Any help much appreciated :)

Please see images below.

Comment: Please re-check the number-format again. If that doesn't help, try to wrap your formula into `VALUE(...)` to ensure the value shown is not treated as text. Also this question may fit better to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) then SO ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're still not getting it after you change the format of the cell, you can surround the index/match formula you've written with =text(b4, "mm/dd/yyyy") which will format the 5 digit number you've gotten as a date.

Comment: Here is my formula: `=""&INDEX('Raw Data'!A:BV,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(A4,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))`

Would this be right? `=TEXT(""&INDEX('Raw Data'!A:BV,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(A4,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))B4, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: sorry, wrong spreadsheet, this is the formula with the TEXT function added: `=TEXT(INDEX('Raw Data'!A:Z,MATCH($B$3,'Raw Data'!A:A,0),MATCH(A4,'Raw Data'!1:1,0))B4,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

I tried the above, Excel returns a caution saying it's a circular reference and then displays the date as `00/01/1900`

Comment: what's the B4 doing at the end of your index function?

Comment: @bdpolinsky - I need a value in the TEXT function, otherwise it won't work

Comment: doesn't the index/match return a value?